# Error when installing Ruby: 'requirements_osx_port_install_port'

Tags: ruby, command-line, installation, rvm

I'm trying to load `Ruby 2.0.0` using `rvm` on my MacBook Pro but I'm getting this error

`('requirements_osx_port_install_port')` and told to

`"please read /Users/Kelsey/.rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p195/1371938583_port_install.log"`.

Other people have apparently had the same problem which for them was fixed by going to

`XCode>Preferences>Downloads>Command Line Tools>Install`

But for me that did no good. Ideas?

Comment: you need to read the file, if you do not understand the content post the file here so someone can help you

Answer (score 0):

After installing xcode, go to xcode>preferences>downloads> Installe the command line Tool when it's done try to restart your terminal session, it should work